# Wordpress - Editing Custom Post Type defined by Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme applied to my wordpress site.

It has its own custom post type named 'company'. I am trying to enable archiving on this post type but I cannot find where I can do that.

Resources online suggest it would be in functions.php of the theme but it does not seem to be there.

Is there anywhere else in Wordpress where an author can define their own custom post types?

Note: It is also not visible within the Types plugin.

Comment: Could be anywhere.  Does your theme have includes? You'll probably want to do a search across files for a keyword, such as 'company'

Comment: Found the correct file by executing this within my theme directory to help find the file that created the company post type.

ls -R | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' | grep 'company'